# Alter field content inside modules hook_node_view

Tags: entities

I'd like to alter, but not save, a fields output.  I've got a MODULE_node_view already setup.  Is there a way to do this?  I don't want to save the output permanently.

Answer (score 1):

In [`HOOK_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) you can alter your fields like this:

```php
function MODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  //be sure to be in full page mode, but you can also user 'teaser'
  if ($view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node)) {
    //kpr($node); => use devel module and kpr() to inspect your node.
    //Change the title of the node
    $node->title = 'New title';

    //Change the "text" field 
    $lang = field_language('node', $node, 'field_text');
    $node->field_text[$lang][0]['value'] = 'New field text value';

    //Change the "body" field which has a slightly different syntax
    $lang = field_language('node', $node, 'body');
    $node->body[$lang][0]['value'] = 'New body value';
  }
}
```

Note the usage of [`field_language()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.multilingual.inc/function/field_language/7) to retrieve the correct value for each field.

Comment: This does not work if you make $node->title = 'New title'; it does not change...

Answer (score -1):

You can print the `$node` array and then access your field through index.

```
print_r($node);
```

Comment: Gee, thanks.  But I need to render the altered field WITHOUT saving it or attaching it to the node.  Any ideas?